# Как сохранить внешний вид текста при парсинге сайта с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Допустим есть html документ следующего вида:

```
<span style="background-color: initial;">
Родился в <strong>1917 </strong>году, с тех пор занимался театральным искусством. </span>
```

Можно ли средствами библиотеки Jsoup сохранить внешний вид текста, например выделение тега  и других ему подобных, или нужно писать свой алгоритм для этого?

Comment: JSOUP не может тут помочь, т.к. он только позволяет работать с HTML в виде структурированных данных. Отображение текста вне его компетенции. Этим TextView/WebView должно заниматься. Для первого будет очень сложно заставить работать любой HTML. Для второго - очень просто, но оно будет тормозить. Выбор за вами.

Comment: Если вы отображаете текст в TextView то попробуйте Html.fromHtml() как описано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/7540461

Answer (score 0):

Если имеются ввиду ввиду оформление для тех же тегов span/strong из вашего примера, предопределенное в CSS - нет, в jsoup данная функциональность отсутствует.

Вам прийдется либо  использовать для получения интересующих вас свойств оформления элементов отдельные библиотеки для парсинга CSS([ph-css](https://github.com/phax/ph-css), [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net)), либо если есть ресурсы - использовать для этой задачи полноценный headless-браузер(через тот же Selenium, либо через API самих браузеров).